# .reshape function sometimes works and sometimes fails on vectorised data

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

So I'm new to the field of machine learning and i'm trying to build a KNN classifier, i noticed this while trying to reshape the array

When i use the `.reshape(100,-1)` i get the following error:

`ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (100, 512)`

Then when i update it to `.reshape(100,1,-1)` i get no error

And when i update it *again* to  `.reshape(100,-1)`, i get no error.

This does not happen everytime i update it or the cell of the python book, but does happen for the majority of the time.

Why does this happen?

Edit: I apologise for not sharing the code snippet, i've added it below

```
vectorized = tfh(df['url'])

df['vectorized_urls'] = np.array(vectorized).reshape((100,-1))
```

Comment: When you use `(100,1,-1)` what's the resulting shape?

Comment: Is the `reshape` that raising the error, or some follow code?  A more typical `reshape` error message is "ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 51712 into shape (100,newaxis)".  The `expected a 1d array` part is puzzling if `reshape` is doing it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @hpaulj for that, the resultant shape is ```(1, 512)``` and for ```(100,-1)```  the resultant shape is ```(100,)```

Comment: @hpaulj i've added the code snippet to my request and the first time i run with ```(100,-1)```  i get the error as

```
ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (100, 512)
```

which i believe is caused due to the missing 1

But when i run with ```(100,1,-1)``` i get no error 

However when i run with the test,train splitting code

Comment: @hpaulj - this a continuation to my previous comment

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

```

I get the error as ```ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [512, 100]``` which does make sense when you check the error message i received.

Now, when i use (100,-1), i get no error with the reshape NOR the splitting snippet.

Comment: I should have insisted on seeing the full traceback.  Now I suspect it's the `df[name]=...` that's raising the error.  Is `df` a pandas dataframe?